# A counter example for the fact that every linear map doesn't have an eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

In the [book](http://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4%E2%80%A6) of *linear algrebra* by Werner Greub, at page $120$, it is given that

To show that every map doesn't have  an eigenvector, it says

> Define $\phi$ in $E$ such that $\phi x_1 = x_2 $ and $\phi x_2 =
> > -x_1$, where $x_1, x_2$ forms a basis for $E$. Assume $a = \delta_1 x_1 + \delta_2 x_2$ is an eigenvector.Then $\phi a = \lambda a$, and
>   hence $$\delta_1^2 + \delta_2^2  = 0 \Rightarrow \delta_1 = 0 =
> > \delta_2$$

But the fact that $$\delta_1^2 + \delta_2^2  = 0$$ doesn't imply that $\delta_1 = 0 = \delta_2$ since 
$$\delta_1^2 + \delta_2^2  = 0 \Rightarrow \delta_1^2 = - \delta_2^2$$
$$\Rightarrow \delta_1 * \delta_2^{-1} = - \delta_1^{-1} * \delta_2 $$
$$\Rightarrow  - (\delta_1 * \delta_2^{-1}) = (\delta_1*\delta_2^{-1})^{-1} $$
i.e $k^{-1} = -k$

and this can happen in a field.

For example, in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ 
$$2 * 3 = 1$$
$$2 + 3 = 0$$
and $$3 = -2$$

So where is the problem ?

Comment: But it can't in $\Bbb F_3$ or $\Bbb F_7$. A better statement would be: For every field $k$ that is *not* algebraically closed, we can find a linear map that does not have eigenvectors. Simply ensure that $\det(\phi-X)$ is irreducible over $k$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Is it obviously "simple" to manufacture a matrix with a given characteristic polynomial?

Comment: (a-b)(a+b)=0 then either a=b v a=-b

Comment: @HenningMakholm Look up [Companion Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix). Basically it is the matrix representing multiplication by $x$ in the ring $K[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ (viewed as a vector space over $K$) with respect to the basis consisting of the cosets of the monomials $x^i, i=0,1,\ldots,\deg p -1$ (or its transpose, I never remember which?)

Comment: @Henning Makholm, it should be easy over $\mathbb R$ since we know that irreducible factors of characteristic polynomial is of degree at most $2$. Thus, for a given characteristic polynomial, build block diagonal matrix, where blocks are either 1x1 corresponding to eigenvalues or 2x2 corresponding to irreducible factors of degree $2$.

Comment: @Ennar: Yes, but Hagen was speaking about an _arbitrary_ not-algebraically-closed field.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Right, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @Henning Makholm, true. Luckily, Jyrki responded with elegant solution. You always learn something new.

Comment: Leth, the fact that the book example (over $\Bbb{R}$) does not have eigenvalues also follows from the fact that the linear transformation is the 90 degree rotation of the $xy$-plane. There cannot be eigenvectors because no non-zero vector of $\Bbb{R}^2$ is a scalar multiple of its rotated version.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen A nice point of view, thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that he is (implicitly) working over $\Bbb R$. The point is not to define a linear map which doesn't have any eigenvalue over any field (what does that even mean?), but to show that there are fields out there with linear maps that don't have an eigenvalue.

Comment: @Leth I don't, but that's hardly relevant. He could be working over $\Bbb Q$ as well, or any of a number of extension fields over $\Bbb Q$. That's not the point, see my edit.

Comment: It says "As an example let E be a real linear space of two dimensions ...".

Comment: You are right, since we are just giving counterexample, any field that that the map doesn't have an eigenvector would work.

Comment: @mfl I missed that part, thanks :)

Comment: @mfl I didn't check the link. So he's _explicitly_ working over $\Bbb R$ instead. It's just hidden in the fine print.